# How to call a method by JSONObject

Tags: java, spring, json

I want to call some methods by `JSONObject`. Here's my code

```
public JSONObject analyticsCustomer()  
{
    JSONObject ju = new JSONObject();
    ju.put("analyticsData",  analyticsCustomerlist());
}
```

Here is the `analyticsCustomerlist()` method:

```
private JSONArray analyticsCustomerlist()
{
    JSONArray analyticsCustomerArrayLast = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        List<ReferralAnalyticsPOJO> analyticsCustomerlist = referralAnalyticsdao
                     .analyticsCustomer();

        JSONArray analyticsCustomerArray = new JSONArray();
        for (ReferralAnalyticsPOJO analytics : analyticsCustomerlist) {
            JSONObject jp = new JSONObject();

            jp.put("label", analytics.getDateDiff());
            jp.put("value", analytics.getCNT());
            analyticsCustomerArray.put(jp);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject1.put("key", "ana");
        jsonObject1.put("values", analyticsCustomerArray);
        analyticsCustomerArrayLast.put(jsonObject1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return analyticsCustomerArrayLast;
}
```

I want to call `analyticsCustomerlist()` by `JSONObject ju`. Can you please tell me the process of calling? Because it shows error.

Comment: You don't return your `JSONObject` and could you please add `analyticsCustomerlist()`? Otherwise we don't know what it does and if it throws errors there.

Comment: `ju ` is object of `JSONObject ` . So you can call only those methods which are provided by `JSONObject`

Comment: Presuming that analyticsCustomerList is a java.util.List, you cant just insert it this way and send it. You would have to iterate through the list, create multiple JsonObjects as an array or list,add each objects attributes in JsonObject,  and send it over.

Comment: if i do   ju.put("analytics",  analyticsCustomerlist()); is it correct way??

Comment: Which error message do you see?